# Can Doctor Strange create a replica of Mjolnir?

Tags: marvel, comics, mjolnir, doctor-strange

After the release of the movie *Thor: Ragnarok*, I keep seeing a fan theory on the Internet saying that Mjolnir might return in *Avengers: Infinity War*.

The logic: Thor took the Mjolnir to Doctor Strange's sanctum and kept it there. Doctor Strange replaced it with a fake Mjolnir which responded to Thor's summon in the end. So, Hela ended up destroying fake Mjolnir and real Mjolnir survived. Doctor Strange did it on the request of Odin, so that Thor could realize that he is *God of Thunder*, not *God of Hammers*.

While this is a beautiful theory and it's possible for Doctor Strange to trap the Mjolnir in a pocket dimension or maze of portals, I am curious to know whether he could really create a replica of Mjolnir. Here, Mjolnir doesn't need to be strong, but it should respond to Thor's summon and be able to do thundering and immovability stuffs upto some extent.

Has Doctor Strange shown such set of powers in comics?

Comment: Couldn't he just use the Time Stone to rewind Mjolnir to a point where it was whole?

Comment: Don't you think there are some spoilers involved in the question ??

Comment: I assume you're referring to Mjolnir being destroyed, which was in every Thor: Ragnarok trailer, so no, it doesn't constitute a spoiler in this case.

Comment: Also, Thor going to the Sanctum is the mid-credits scene of Doctor Strange, so that's not a spoiler either. One could make an argument for the mention of _God of Hammers_, but I don't think it's enough to warrant spoiler blocks breaking up the question.

Comment: I think Doctor Strange could create a replica of the hammer but as for the enchantments i don't think Dr. Strange is as powerful as Odin and wouldn't be able to put the original enchantments on it

Comment: @Tomsta Good point, but did any one else try to use his hammer before it was destroyed after he visited Doctor Strange to "test" the charm? I do not remember. Maybe they lucked out that no one else tried to use it in that time?

Comment: @Odin1806 My comic book knowledge isn't that good i've only got into Superhero's through the MCU

Answer (score 2):

In *Thor* #600 Mjolnir is damaged in a fight with Bor. It is never fully destroyed but rather partially broken. Later in *Thor* #602 Thor goes to Doctor Strange asking him to fix Mjolnir for him. To fix it Strange channels the Odinforce, if he is able to channel it to fix Mjolnir it is possible he can do the same to recreate it from scratch.

[image: Strange starts the process of fixing Mjolnir] [image: The magic starts to take effect]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

[image: Strange fixes Mjolnir]